# Function scope & variables in/out of said function

Tags: javascript

So im studying and just trying something out and well, the question is this

i know that a variable defined outside of a function is avail to all while one set inside a function is not.

that said when i do this

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" name="field" id="field"/>

<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"/>
```

**JS**:

```
var results = document.getElementById("field").value;
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");

function pushit(){
    aNames.push(results);
    for(i=0; i<aNames.length; i++){
        document.write(aNames[i] + "<br/>");
    }

    submitBtn.onclick = pushit;
}
```

it doesn't work. when submit is hit, it just displays the original array items.

but when i change the function to this:

```
function pushit(){
    var results = document.getElementById("field").value;
    aNames.push(results);
    for(i=0; i<aNames.length; i++){
         document.write(aNames[i] + "<br/>");
    }
}
```

essentially just putting the var results inside the function it works. my ? is why?

if i was to say for example, check in a form for a specific value of a field in the form, id check in the same manner, for the "value" of it against what i wanted to check so...im just not understanding why it doesnt work.

any tips, links, explanations etc...i gladly appreciate.

Comment: sorry it was a mess i forgot to "code" to coded parts so it threw it all together..its better now

Comment: please define "doesn't work".  As written there's no obvious reason why the duplicate definition of `results` in the first version would prevent the posted code from working.

Comment: @Alnitak see the whole edit history, confusing stuff going on there.

Comment: ah, so that explains that - the original code you posted wasn't the right code!

Comment: @GGG yeah, noted - I thought Rocket had made that edit, not the OP.

Comment: @GGG: The OP made the edit, then Justin Niessner edited the post and accidently added the line back, so I edited it to match what the OP wanted posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `results` variable in the first example, is set when the page loads, and is never changed.    Each time you read it, it's the same value.

In the second example, you are getting the value from the input each time the event is ran; you are making a new variable.  Thus, you are seeing the new values.

JavaScript DOM elements are "live" variables, but strings aren't.

For example:

```
var results = document.getElementById("field");
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");

function pushit(){
    alert(results.results);
}
```

This works as `results` is a "live" variable.  When you access it, it's always the latest DOM element.

When you do `var results = document.getElementById("field").value;`, now `results` is just a string; it's not "live" anymore.

Comment: So what you mean to say is, when the code is read, the value of "result" is empty(or whatever is the default ) so then its status doesnt change...its checked again when the button is pressed....GOTCHA! i thought itd be persistent throughout but...on btn press, it only checks whats inside the function! thank you for clearing it up.